# tableHeaderView y-position is far below zero

Tags: swift, tableview, uitapgesturerecognizer, tableheader

I have a grouped UITableView which had extra spacing on top because of the `.grouped` style. On StackOverflow, I found the following solution which works great:

```
var tableHeaderFrame = CGRect.zero
tableHeaderFrame.size.height = CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude
myTableView.tableHeaderView = UIView(frame: tableHeaderFrame)
```

However, I have a `UITapGestureRecognizer` which looks up the frame of the sender and tries to allocate the right section for it, like this:

```
if let headerView = sender.view?.superview as? MyTableHeader {
    let headerLocation = headerView.frame
    var pressedSection: Int!
    print("header loc: ", headerLocation)

    for section in 0 ... tableData.count - 1 {
        print(MyTableView.rect(forSection: section))
        let sectionRect = MyTableView.rect(forSection: section)
        if(sectionRect.contains(headerLocation)) {
            pressedSection = section
        }
    }
}
```

I need this to update my `tableData` array as it is a custom button to remove a section. However, when I press the button in the **first** section, the app crashes (pressedSection = nil) and I see this output for the rect:

```
(0.0, 1.1754943508222875e-38, 337.5, 207.4468085106383)
```

Which clearly indicates a weird value for the y position. I think this is because of the `.leastNormalMagnitude.` When I remove the code above for the tableHeaderFrame, the error is gone but the spacing is back. How can I solve both issues: let the frame values be 'normal' and remove the top padding/space?

Comment: `1.1754943508222875e-38` is not far below zero. That's a really, really small, but positive, value very close to zero. It's really `0.00000many more00117549435080222875`. Just use `0` since that is essentially what it is.

Comment: Ah, well yeah, but that makes for the unrecognizable view, as my first cell starts at a y-position of 0. I am now thinking of simply adding tags to my section headers to make them recognizable, but I read somewhere that .tag values are bad for many reasons (without actually mentioning any reason - ha). Would this be a great solution according to you? `let pressedSection = headerView.tag` instead of iterating through the sections as in the second block of code.